# What is the strong way of ddosing?

Tags: security, ddos

Can you give me some information about the strongest way of ddos attack ? 
Is botnet the strongest way of ddosing ? 
Thanks in advace

Comment: I highly recommend botnets for all your DDOSsing needs :-)

Comment: Isn't this type of question better asked over at serverfault.com?

Comment: This is not a question for serverfault,  they have no idea what computational complexity is.   Most botnets do a  HTTP get request to the front page,  its not the best but it works.  Most botnet software comes with syn bomb and icmp flood,  but toughs attacks are much easier to filter than a flood of HTTP GETs.

Comment: @XIII,I think the moderators should migrate this question to security.stackexchange.com